# Unable to get "yo azuresfjava:AddService" command to work

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am running Service Fabric for Linux (preview) on Azure on a 2 node cluster. I have deployed 2 instances of one service of my application running as docker containers on one of the nodes using the command "yo azuresfjava" and selecting the "Container" as the framework for my service. I am trying to add another service to the same application using "yo azuresfjava:AddService" as explained in the documentation but I get the following message when I run this command. How can I get the "yo azuresfjava:AddService" command to work ? Thanks

```
root@vjsflinux:/dhapp# yo azuresfguest:AddService
```

> Error azuresfguest:AddService
>
> You don’t seem to have a generator with the name
>   “azuresfguest:AddService” installed. But help is on the way:
>
> You can see available generators via npm search yeoman-generator or
>   via http://yeoman.io/generators/. Install them with npm install
>   generator-azuresfguest:AddService.
>
> To see all your installed generators run yo without any arguments.
>   Adding the --help option will also show subgenerators.
>
> If yo cannot find the generator, run yo doctor to troubleshoot your
>   system.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using two different commands: `yo azuresfjava:AddService` and `yo azuresfguest:AddService`

If you type yo --help, you'll see that only the first (azuresfjava) has the option to add a service (AddService).

Comment: Does "yo azuresfguest:AddService" command not exist ? If it does not exist, how the service fabric documentation found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-container-linux mentioning the use of this command to add a guest service to an deployed service fabric application type. If this command does not exist, how can one add and deploy more than one guest service to a deployed service fabric application type.

Comment: Unfortunately that is correct, it doesn't work right now. They're working on it. As a workaround, you can manually add the new service to the application manifest. (e.g. create a new project and copy paste relevant bits over)

Comment: Can you post a sample ApplicationManifest.xml with multiple services in it, that I can mimic when I hand edit it to add multiple services ?

Comment: Does this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-multiple-apps

Comment: Well, this link talks about how to add multiple services to an Application in Service Fabric on Windows. I am looking for a doc that explains how to add multiple docker containers (Guests) to a Application in Service Fabric on Linux.